# Maven - deploy:deploy-file over series of files within ${project.build.directory} (target/)

Tags: java, maven, deployment, wsdl, kuali

Quick briefing on my situation - I'm working on a code base that has JAX-WS annotated interfaces/classes that we generate code-first wsdls from.  We are using CXF's cxf-java2ws-plugin to generate wsdls at build time within maven for inclusion within the .jar produced for each module.

What we'd like to do is deploy these wsdl files to a maven repository since the maven repository can act as

- a makeshift service repository (such as described [here](http://myarch.com/using-maven-repository-as-web-services-registry))
- give clients an easy way to use the [cxf codegen plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) by pointing to the maven coordinates for a wsdl instead of managing the wsdl files themselves

What I've got so far is a pom file that uses dependency:unpack-dependencies to get all of the wsdl files in the project in to one directory within this modules ${project.build.directory} (commonly known as target/ to everyone out there).

What I don't know how to do is to loop through each of these files and invoke [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) mojo on each wsdl.  What are my options here since I really want to automate the process of deploying these wsdl files and not have anyone ever deploy them manually?

For completeness sake, here is the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>rice</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.kuali.rice</groupId>
        <version>2.0.0-m7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>rice-dist-wsdl</artifactId>
    <name>Rice WSDL Distributions</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <wsdl.location>${project.build.directory}/wsdl</wsdl.location>
    </properties>


    <!-- Depends on all API modules and modules that generate or contain wsdls -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-kew-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-kim-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-krms-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-ksb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-shareddata-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-wsdls</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>**\/*.wsdl</includes>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Which shoves the wsdls in target/wsdl (they are contained within wsdl/ inside each .jar being depended upon):

```
[whaley@sunspot ~/Repositories/Kuali/rice/dist-wsdl] 
> find . -iname '*.wsdl' | head -3
./target/wsdl/CampusService.wsdl
./target/wsdl/CountryService.wsdl
./target/wsdl/CountyService.wsdl
```

---

**Solution**

Thought what I implemented was different than the accepted answer provided by Ryan Steward, I accepted his answer since it led me to write my own.

Basically, here is a maven pom that's a submodule in the multi-module project described above.  I'm using dependency:unpack-dependencies and then using an in-line groovy script to call deploy:deploy-file on each of those wsdl files.  It's a bit of a hackjob, but I couldn't think of a better way to do this without hardcoding paths to the wsdl files in the module and calling several executions of the deploy:deploy-file mojo on them, leading to a very verbose pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>rice</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.kuali.rice</groupId>
        <version>2.0.0-m7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>rice-dist-wsdl</artifactId>
    <name>Rice WSDL Distributions</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <wsdl.location>${project.build.directory}/wsdl</wsdl.location>
    </properties>


    <!-- Depends on all API modules and modules that generate or contain wsdls -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-kew-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-kim-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-krms-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-ksb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rice-shareddata-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-wsdls</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>**\/*.wsdl</includes>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>
                                def repo_url
                                def repo_id
                                if ("${project.version}".endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) {
                                    repo_url = "${kuali.repository.snapshot.url}"
                                    repo_id = "${kuali.repository.snapshot.id}"
                                } else {
                                    repo_url = "${kuali.repository.release.url}"
                                    repo_id = "${kuali.repository.release.id}"
                                }

                                def wsdlGroupId = "${project.groupId}.wsdl"
                                new File("${wsdl.location}").eachFile() { file ->
                                    serviceName = file.name.split("\\.")[0]

                                    log.info("Deploying ${wsdlGroupId}:${serviceName}:wsdl:${project.version} to ${repo_id}")

                                    execString = "mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=${file} -Durl=${repo_url} -DrepositoryId=${repo_id} "
                                    execString += "-DgroupId=${wsdlGroupId} -DartifactId=${serviceName} "
                                    execString += "-Dversion=${project.version} -Dpackaging=wsdl -Dclassifier=wsdl"

                                    def proc = execString.execute()
                                    proc.waitFor()

                                    err = proc.err.text
                                    if (err != null &amp;&amp; err.length() > 0) {
                                        log.error(err)
                                        fail("Deployment failed for ${wsdlGroupId}:${serviceName}:wsdl:${project.version} to ${repo_id}.  \n Run in verbose mode for full error.")
                                    } else {
                                        log.info("Successfully deployed ${wsdlGroupId}:${serviceName}:wsdl:${project.version} to ${repo_id}")
                                    }
                                }
                            </source>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I like this very much.  I need to do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility: the Maven Ant tasks can [deploy files](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/install-deploy.html). I've never used it, but I'll bet you could use an antrun configuration and some ant pattern matching to pick up and deploy all the WSDLs.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this but with GMaven (groovy's maven plugin) by in-lining a script that loops the wsdl file names and calls `mvn deploy:deploy-file on each of them.  Thanks for your answer and making me think to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The Build Helper plugin might help you out. You can make it publish the WSDLs, but you'll have to list each one out explicitly, and they'll all have the artifactId of your pom in their names. Only the classifier can change. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-WSDLs</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/foo.wsdl</file>
                        <classifier>foo</classifier>
                        <type>wsdl</type>
                    </artifact>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/bar.wsdl</file>
                        <classifier>bar</classifier>
                        <type>wsdl</type>
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If your pom's coordinate is myGroupId:myArtifactId:1.1.1, then the artifacts installed and deployed using this config would be named myArtifactId-1.1.1-foo.wsdl and myArtifactId-1.1.1-bar.wsdl. That's the best I know of.

Comment: I could do that... but i'm dealing with a potentially variable number of .wsdl files whose names I might not know ahead of time.